# how does android give the correct convertView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I implemented a Section List View following instruction from https://nodeload.github.com/necronet/section-list/zip/master. 
Everything working fine, but just out of curiosity, I want to know how Android OS give me correct convertView in the `getView` function of the Adapter (code below). There are two types of views (two different layout files), one SectionView and ItemView. Imagine a situation, when a fist section and an item are scrolled out of the screen, so there are two views that are in the View Recycler. Then a new view is about to be scrolled in from the bottom. In the `getView` function, I have to check the position, by the function `isSection`, to determine what view should I give at that position. The amazing thing is that Android OS (or whatever underlying) always give me the correct convertView (among the two types of views in the Recycler) to recycle, how does it know before I even check? Thanks.

```
 public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,
                        final ViewGroup parent) {
        if (isSection(position)) {
            return getSectionView(convertView, sectionPositions.get(position));
        }
        return getItemView(getLinkedPosition(position), convertView,
                parent);
    }
```

Comment: You're always working with the position, so I don't think there is any black magic being done.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I can easily break that function using a random, say if rand()>0.5 return getSectionView, else return getItemView

Comment: (continue from previous comment) so that the convertView doesn't match with the View I'm gonna render

Comment: @cplain has a good answer. To elaborate, when you do `rand()>0.5` and then based on that call one of the `getView()` methods, you're potentially passing off the wrong recycled view. Since ahead of time, the "proper" `convertView` was chosen, you break the adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my understanding of how `getView` works in an adapter:

This will return what 'type' of view the particular item in the list is - and thus use the correct `convertView` in `getView()`

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

And this returns how many different types of views there are:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

Of course these don't return 0 in proper code.

Comment: Yes, I checked the code, the original author did implement those 2 fucntions, tks you and @A--C

Comment: Might be helpful to s/o:
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(final int position) {
        if (isSection(position)) {
            return viewTypeCount - 1;
        }else
            return viewTypeCount -2;


    }